# WPF unable to select enabled item within ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox, itemcontainerstyle

I'm trying to create a ComboBox with some items within the selection list enabled and others disabled.  Visually, I'm able to do this but when I select an item that is visually enabled, nothing happens.

XAML:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding EndpointModel.DisplayFormat}" 
          VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,10,0" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding EndpointModel.SelectMediaFormat}">
     <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
          <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
              <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsEnabled}" />
          </Style>
     </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
     <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
              <ComboBoxItem>
                 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
              </ComboBoxItem>
          </DataTemplate>
     </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

[image]

When I click on the selected item above, nothing happens - EndpointModel.SelectMediaFormat is not executed.

The moment I remove the **ComboBox.ItemTemplate** stanza, I can successfully select any enabled item, i.e.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding EndpointModel.DisplayFormat}" 
          VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,10,0" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding EndpointModel.SelectMediaFormat}">
     <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
          <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
              <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsEnabled}" />
          </Style>
     </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ComboBox>
```

[image]

As you can see, i'm displaying the object reference.  I can't figure out how to replace the above with the actual Names.

I'm quite new at WPF, as you can imagine :-)

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "execute the selected item"?

Comment: I replaced that sentence with "select any enabled item" - hope that is clearer.

Comment: So when you try to select ```Image``` in the example above, nothing happens - the dropdown box stays open?

Comment: Correct.  The Binding property (Endpoint.SelectedMediaFormat) is not executed and the dropdown box stays open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `DisplayMemberPath` property to `Name` (The property that you want to display).

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding EndpointModel.DisplayFormat}" 
          VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,10,0" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding EndpointModel.SelectMediaFormat}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name">
     <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
          <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
              <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsEnabled}" />
          </Style>
     </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Thank you.  I will research the 'DisplayMemberPath' to better understand the magic here.

Comment: It just looks for a corresponding property name to bind to for each of your items in your item source.